# Screen doesn't awake with mouse movement and requires key press

Tags: mouse, windows-11, lock-screen, wake-up

I set the screen timeout to 5min, so after that time the screen turns off. Sleep mode is disabled,
so the screen turns off but the computer is still running.

My problem is that instead of just the screen turning off, windows also goes to the lock screen.

Even if I [disable the lock screen](https://gearupwindows.com/how-to-turn-off-on-lock-screen-on-windows-11/), I still need to press space bar / Enter / Esc keys for the screen to awake.

I want the screen to immediately awake when I move the mouse, without having to press any keys. This is the behavior I have on my other Windows 10 devices. How can I do this for Windows 11?

Comment: Maybe it's the new paradigm? macOS shifted to that behaviour maybe 8 or 10 years ago, which I originally found irritating, but actually prefer it now - no more wakeups if you just accidentally jog the desk.

Comment: I don't like my mouse waking up my machine. I have taken steps to prevent that. Try a physically wired mouse. That will likely work.